# Дашборды по кнопкам в Jupyter Notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook

Могу ли я в Jupyter Notebook сделать так, чтоб мое начальство могло просматривать графические элементы по данным, с интеракциями (кнопками для их переключения).
Чтоб они (начальство) могли переключать по нескольким кнопкам дашборды с графиками, а кнопки бы отвечали за тематику дашборда (например, одна кнопка с графиками по одной группе, другая по другой группе и т.д.). И чтоб были скрыты элементы типа кода и прочих лишних элементов, не понятных и не нужных рядовому пользователю.

И если это возможно, то какие библиотеки для этого понадобятся.

Если же нет, посоветуйте, пожалуйста, программы, в которых бы это было возможно реализовать(по типу power bi, я полагаю) и с максимально удобным и простым интерфейсом. Но эта часть вопроса не так важна.

Comment: Еще streamlit посмотрите, как вариант ([обзор на Хабре](https://habr.com/ru/post/473196/)). Через jupyter notebook то что вы хотите точно не получится.

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать, например, фреймворк [Dash](https://dash.plotly.com/). Посмотрите [галерею](https://dash-gallery.plotly.host/Portal/) что можно делать с его помощью.

Answer (score 0):

Фреймворки это не моя область, слишком много времени уйдет на изучение, при том, что результатом будет всего лишь небольшое увеличение удобства. Решил остановиться на power bi, правда пока не знаю как на нем реализовать все вышесказанное. Буду разбираться. Всем спасибо за ответы